# MySQL - La columna en field list es desconocida

Tags: mysql, sql

Escribo la siguiente instrucción tal como en el curso que estoy haciendo:

```
SELECT EMPRESA, DIRECCION, POBLACION FROM CLIENTES
```

y cuando le doy en correr me sale lo siguiente.

Error:

consulta SQL: Copiar Documentación

```
SELECT EMPRESA, 
       DIRECCION, 
       POBLACION 
FROM CLIENTES 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

> ## 1054 - La columna 'DIRECCION' en field list es desconocida

Comment: Agrega la estructura de tu tabla para ide todo se el error, has un `describe nombredetutabla`

Comment: ¿Y tienes una columna `DIRECCION` en la tabla?

Comment: asi es amigo. lo hago tal como en el curso, y a el le funciona

Comment: Considera agregar lo que te comenté, casi seguro que lo escribiste mal

Comment: gracias amigo por tu respuesta,pero no funciono

Comment: En definitiva te indica que le es desconocido "DIRECCION" podría ser que tenga algún carácter extraño en la columna-campo, que de verdad no exista o no se llame así, generalmente por eso arroja este error al no encontrar una coincidencia.  has tu consulta por partes ve que si te regresa y que no.

Comment: oye las tildes tienen que ver?, el escribe con tildes tal como estan en la tabla, pero cuando yo lo hago me sale sin tilde

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que te arroja la consulta `show columns from CLIENTES ;` o ` select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = "CLIENTES ";`?

Comment: nada de eso amigo, solo Error
consulta SQL: Copiar Documentación


SELECT EMPRESA, DIRECCION, POBLACION FROM CLIENTES LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1054 - La columna 'DIRECCION' en field list es desconocida

Comment: @yormanlopez los comandos que te recomiendas así como el que yo te dije es para que veas los nombres de las columnas de tu tabla, consejo trata de seguir las recomendaciones pues son para ayudar!

Comment: les agradezco, para ser sincero no te entendi nada de tus recomendaciones ya que estoy estoy aprendiendo sql.cual era el error? que las palabras direccion y poblacion en la tabla aparecian con tiildes. tuve que escribir esas palabras en word con tildes copiarlas y pegarlas.pero que me aconsejan ya que cuando hago la consulta no me da la palabra con tilde. muchas gracias

Comment: buenas, como bien han dicho previamente, prueba a hacer un DESC CLIENTES para ver la estructura de tu tabla y ver como tienes declarado el campo. Es muy probable que lo hayas escrito con un acento que ahora no te muestre y por eso no reconoce el campo.

Answer (score 0):

el problema de esa tabla es que las columnas en el curso de pildoras informaticas el profesor coloca la sentencia

```
SELECT EMPRESA, DIRECCION, POBLACION FROM CLIENTES ,
```

pero al exportar la bd las columnas toman por defecto los siguientes nombres a,b,c,d,e..  dado por entonces para que se te de la sentencia, deberias colocar asi select a, b, c from clientes asi se te va funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar ese problema solo debes ir a estructuras en cada tabla (clientes y productos) y cambiar los nombres que tengan espacios (Número de pedido --> Númerodepedido).